# How do I capitalize every letter that has a period immediately after it in Javascript in a concise manner?

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following string `A.b.c. This is an example`

I would like to make it so that any letters which have a period immediately after them are capital.

This is the code I currently have, which works. Any ideas on how to make this more concise?

```js
let testString = 'A.b.c. This is an example'
const pieces = testString.split('.')

let tempString = ''
let replaceString = ''
pieces.forEach(piece => {
  if (piece.length === 1) {
    tempString += piece.toUpperCase() + '.'
    replaceString += piece + '.'
  }
})

let newString = testString.replace(replaceString, tempString)
console.log(newString)

//A.B.C. This is an example
```

Comment: "This is the code I currently have, which works." ... if it works, then what is the problem?

Comment: What do you think is "unclean" about it?

Comment: @mardubbles Is SO not a place for learning how to solve a problem more efficiently or in a more concise manner?

Comment: @JamesParker It is, when you explain what is inefficient about what you are doing or which part of your code is making you gasp. If you just want a code review, check out  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JuanMendes Thank you for the clarification. I will definitely check that out.

Comment: @JamesParker mplungjan already gave you a great suggestion, but yes, we like questions that state a clear problem; "general improvements to my code" are not the intention of SO.

Comment: No slights intended, but I personally like your code as is. Now if on "runtime execution wise", say if in a loop identified for "bottleneck" (where execution matters) ... obviously your solution and any regex way would need to be compared on timings @JamesParker

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a regular expression and a custom replacement function. It may look cleaner if you're not bothered by the ugliness of regular expressions.

```js
let testString = 'A.b.c. This is an example.';
let newString = testString.replace(/\w\./g, letter => letter.toUpperCase());
console.log(newString);
```

Comment: Who knows. This is exactly what I was looking for though. Thank you.

Comment: Always avoided regular expressions, I still do. Regular experssions are difficult to learn. Nice solution by the way.

Comment: I know why. You have to not do that when you have trailing punctuation

Comment: My example doesn't include trailing punctuation, but that is a good consideration.

Comment: @mplungjan but of coursE. :D

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh This is a very simple RegExp. I agree with avoiding very complex RegExps but this is almost as basic as it gets.

Comment: [Replacement functions in RegExps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) FTW!